# Почему sql server требует значение null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть такой код -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Сотрудники] (
[Id]            INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Имя]           NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Фамлия]        NCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Отчество]      NCHAR (50) NULL,
[Дата рождения] DATE       NOT NULL,
[Должность]     INT        NOT NULL,
[Отдел]         INT        NOT NULL,
[Кабинет]       INT        NOT NULL,
[Контакты]      INT        NOT NULL,
[Город]         NCHAR (50) NULL, 
[Адрес]         NCHAR(100) NULL, 
[Телефон]       NCHAR(10)  NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

Если я поставлю в Город, адрес или телефон not null, то при обновлении будет ошибка -

> Warnings
>   The column Адрес on table [dbo].[Сотрудники] must be changed from NULL to NOT NULL. If the table contains data, the ALTER script may not work. To avoid this issue, you must add values to this column for all rows or mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of smart-defaults as a deployment option

Почему так? Почему имя или фамилия могут быть notNull, а последнее три столбца нет?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ты смотри: и ведь дубликатов нет, чем закрыть. Перенёс из комментариев в ответ.

Comment: Подскажите чем делали animated gif?

Comment: @MaxU [Этим](http://www.screentogif.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что у вас в существующей таблице уже есть значения город, адрес или телефон с NULL.

Вам нужно сначала проапдейтить эти записи, а потом уже делать Alter table.

В общем-то вам об этом прямым текстом написано в сообщении об ошибке.

Comment: Где? И не делаю я никаких алертов, я нажимаю на update, а потом update database

Comment: @xomem Где именно вы нажимаете на update? Я правильно понимаю, что у вас есть существующая таблица с данными и вы её как-то пытаетесь поменять? (Возможно, вам стоит внести уточнения в вопрос) И что показывает запрос `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Сотрудники] WHERE [Адрес] is NULL`?

Comment: [вот](https://imgur.com/a/HArUb)

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Сотрудники] WHERE [Адрес] is NULL = 1

Comment: Ну, значит, у вас есть какая-то одна строка, в которой Адрес равен NULL. И, пока эта строка останется в базе - сделать обновление, запрещающее в адресе хранить NULL не будет выполнено. Либо удалите эту строку, либо замените в ней NULL на какое-то иное значение, либо откажитесь от замены типа поля с NULL на NOT NULL.

Comment: Спасибо АК. Помогло.